# Computer algebra system for applying Cartan's test to systems of PDEs

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, kahler-manifolds, exterior-derivative, cartan-geometry

It is my understanding that if one has a (possibly overdetermined) system of PDEs, one can check for compatibility by applying Cartan's test (see for example [1], Chapter 7). It involves first writing the equations as an Exterior Differential System. My question is this: is there a Computer Algebra system that, given a system of PDEs, can apply this test for you?

> [1] Ivey, Thomas Andrew, and Joseph M. Landsberg. Cartan for beginners: differential geometry via moving frames and exterior differential systems. Vol. 61. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society, 2003.

Comment: https://math.colorado.edu/~jnc/Maple.html

Comment: Do you have an example of a system of PDEs that you want to test? Are your systems linear or nonlinear?

Comment: Thank you so much. My equations are nonlinear. For example, one of my systems is 3 nonlinear equations, two dependent variables, and 2 independent. 4th order in x, 1st order in t. I checked that phixxxxt=phitxxxx to check compatibility, where phi is a dependent variable. I will download the program. If you have used it and have advised, please let me know.